# Where to find and install org.osgi.framework package?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, apache-felix

I am trying to follow this tutorial:

[apache felix tutorial #1](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/tutorials-examples-and-presentations/apache-felix-osgi-tutorial/apache-felix-tutorial-example-1.html)

But I don't understand the directory structure.  Where do I place the Activator.java file?  Where, relative to the Activator.java file do I place the MANIFEST.MF?

In this tutorial when I try to compile the Activator.java file, I get errors that org.osgi.framework does not exist.  Where can I get the org.osgi.framework package and where should it be installed?  How does the javac build command know how to find the org.osgi.framework package?

I am looking for a tutorial that explains what Karaf/Felix framework is and how to get simple examples to work.

I have also tried to follow this tutorial:  http://kevinboone.net/osgitest.html

but it is out of date and the building of the Tick bundle step fails.  Specifically, the command:

```
javac -d target/tick/classes -classpath /path/to/karaf/lib/karaf.jar src/net/kevinboone/osgitest/tick/*.java
```

Does not make sense because there is not a file "karaf.jar" in my karaf installation that I downloaded from [karaf download site](https://karaf.apache.org/download.html).

In the manifest file, there is the line:

```
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework
```

but this package does not seem to exist in the karaf installation?

Comment: From the off-topic section: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.* So telling us that the tutorial your following, is broken, is pretty much irrelevant and not in our power to solve. Maybe contact the tutorial author to update it so that it works again

Comment: The fact that you complete a tutorial using an IDE doesn't mean you won't understand the basics. Sometimes it even can help you. I strongly recommend you use, for example, Eclipse IDE. It will help you understand the project structure among other important things.

Comment: About your question _Where do I place the Activator.java file?_ and _Where, relative to the Activator.java file do I place the MANIFEST.MF?_... the `Activator.java` just needs to be in the project classpath (usually `src/your/package/names`) and the `MANIFEST.MF`, inside a `META-INF` folder.

Comment: I did try to contact the tutorial author.  I have not received a response.

Comment: I am also willing to follow a tutorial using Eclipse.  But I have not found one that works yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The felix tutorial is horribly outdated.

If you want to learn OSGi I can recommend the [Apache Karaf demo](https://karaf.apache.org/documentation.html) and [tutorials](http://liquid-reality.de/Karaf-Tutorial/) as well as the [enroute](https://enroute.osgi.org/) examples.

Still to answer the question. You find the package `org.osgi.framework` in the osgi core spec jar and also in the felix jar. So one of these jars needs to be on the classpath during your compile.

You should not create the manifest by hand. Instead use a plugin like the maven-bundle-plugin to create it. You can then place the Activator where ever you want and simply need to give the tool a hint where it is.

Do not invest too much time into Activator and other low level OSGi APIs. They are not the way you should write code. Instead take a look at declarative services. It allows to wire your classes using annotations an takes care of the difficult low level tasks.

The issue with the tutorial is that they use really low level commands like `javac`. Nowadays you should always use a build tool such as Maven or Gradle and declare the dependencies there. The tutorials and examples I linked all provide nice builds that you can also use for your later production code.