# Why am I getting a BundleException when starting my minimal example bundle with Apache Felix Gogo?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I am trying to learn OSGI from the bottom up. Starting with making and running a [minimal example bundle](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/tutorials-examples-and-presentations/apache-felix-osgi-tutorial/apache-felix-tutorial-example-1.html).

I have set up a simple project using maven and the previously linked example from the apache felix website. This minimal project seems to compile nicely and I can see no problem when inspecting the contents of the resulting .jar file.

I then install the resulting bundled .jar file in apache felix's gogo osgi-terminal tool using `felix:install <mybundle.jar>`. After that I try starting it using `felix:start <mybundle.jar>`.

This is when my problem occurs. I get a stacktrace of a org.osgi.framework.BundleException.

So this is the problem I'm trying to fix. I see no apparent problem nor solution that might help or explain why I'm geting this problem.

I'm also using the apache felix framework version 6.0.3 to run my bundle.

So, my question is: Why am I getting these problems, and what can I do to resolve them so that I can get back on track learning OSGI?

I have been searching the great internet for its infinite wisdom considering all things technical, but cannot find anyone having hade the same problem under these same circumstances.

For further information, I'm using Java 12 and the Maven that's built in to IntelliJ Idea Community Edition. I had the same problem using Java 8 with this same setup and have upgraded to 12 just because it felt smart to do so sooner than later.

The OSGI-Activator class, which is the only code in this project so far is as shows below:

```java
package com.github.hannesknutsson.privatepkg;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceEvent;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceListener;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator, ServiceListener {

    private BundleContext context;

    public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        context = bundleContext;

        System.out.println("Starting to listen for service events.");
        context.addServiceListener(this);
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Stopped listening for service events.");
    }

    public void serviceChanged(ServiceEvent serviceEvent) {
        String[] objectClass = (String[])
                serviceEvent.getServiceReference().getProperty("objectClass");

        if (serviceEvent.getType() == ServiceEvent.REGISTERED)
        {
            System.out.println(
                    "Ex1: Service of type " + objectClass[0] + " registered.");
        }
        else if (serviceEvent.getType() == ServiceEvent.UNREGISTERING)
        {
            System.out.println(
                    "Ex1: Service of type " + objectClass[0] + " unregistered.");
        }
        else if (serviceEvent.getType() == ServiceEvent.MODIFIED)
        {
            System.out.println(
                    "Ex1: Service of type " + objectClass[0] + " modified.");
        }
    }
}
```

The Maven pom.xml used to compile and package the results into a bundled .jar file is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <artifactId>testproject</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.github.hannesknutsson</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <artifactId>TestBundle</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Export-Package>${project.groupId}.services</Export-Package>
                        <Private-Package>${project.groupId}.privatepkg</Private-Package>
                        <Bundle-Activator>${project.groupId}.privatepkg.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
                <version>4.2.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>12</source>
                    <target>12</target>
                </configuration>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The resulting stacktrace of this is as follows:

```java
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to cache bundle: TestBundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:3231)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:147)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:120)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.command.Basic.start(Basic.java:734)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Reflective.invoke(Reflective.java:139)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:91)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:599)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:526)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:415)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.doCall(Pipe.java:416)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.call(Pipe.java:229)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.call(Pipe.java:59)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: TestBundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
        at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:650)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.createURL(SecureAction.java:256)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarRevision.initialize(JarRevision.java:148)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.JarRevision.<init>(JarRevision.java:76)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleArchive.createRevisionFromLocation(BundleArchive.java:799)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleArchive.reviseInternal(BundleArchive.java:480)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleArchive.<init>(BundleArchive.java:148)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.create(BundleCache.java:462)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.installBundle(Felix.java:3227)
        ... 19 more
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: TestBundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: Did you try to install using a file: URL to your test bundle?

Comment: I moved the bundle directly to the working directory so that I would only have to specify its name from the Felix terminal. Felix is finding the bundle (it gives me positive messages when installing it). The framework gives me a number for my bundle when I install it, but when I start it I get the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Felix expects a URI when you install the bundle. Try to either use a full file: url.

Alternatively you can download the felix distribution and put your bundle into the bundle dir.

In general be aware that the felix tutorial is a bit outdated and uses some very low level approaches that you would never use in production.

See the answer to this question: [Where to find and install org.osgi.framework package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55829257/where-to-find-and-install-org-osgi-framework-package)

Comment: I have downloaded the felix distribution and have tried launching it with the bundle inside the bundle directory. It gives me the same problem as above.

Comment: how is the URI meant to look? I'm pretty sure felix finds my bundle, the wierd thing is why it refuses to start correctly.

Comment: I guess one part of felix does not care about the url and just loads your bundle. The other part checks for the url syntax and fails. A url must have a scheme like file:. I guess your url is missing this. In general I would simply try to avoid such urls. In the answer to the linked question you find tutorials that use karaf or bndtools for assembling your application. Both are a lot better than fiddling with those urls and individual bundles.

Comment: That sounds strange .. can you put your bundle source in a github project. Then I can take a look.

Comment: Thank you very much for being so helpful. I put my sources in [this github repo](https://github.com/hannesknutsson/osgi-minimal-bundle-test) for you to review if you have the time and will to do so.

I will be sure to check out Apache Karaf. It seems like a nice variety on the OSGI framework.

Comment: There were a few issues in your project. The main one was that you added the maven plugins as dependencies.. I created a PR with the fixes. Btw. Sorry that I did not spot that one right away in the pom you posted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of the help! I will be looking in to what I did wrong and try to get my Karaf skills rolling :)